# Don't have access in Azure Portal to create new items

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-virtual-machine, azureportal

I was added as a global administrator to a company's Azure AD directory. When I try to create a new web app I get the following message:

> You are currently signed into the '-company- (Default Directory)' directory which does not have any subscriptions. You have other directories you can switch to or you can sign up for a new subscription.

When I try to sign up for a new subscription it wants me to enter my payment information, which I do not want to do. I want to use the company's existing subscription.

I also cannot see the App Service that the admin of the account just created in the portal.

It seems like I'm not fully configured, but we thought adding me as Global Administrator should give me exactly what he has, which is what we want. What else do we need to do so we have the same access, and can see each other's items?

Comment: This question is off topic for StackOverflow, but... try changing the directory you're viewing (should be via the gear symbol in the upper-right of the portal). There should be a list of subscriptions associated with your login credentials. My guess is that you need to choose the one associated with your company's Azure subscription.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Is this a ServerFault question? Where's a better place to ask it?

Comment: Also, I have two directories available, and I've checked both of them with no luck.

Comment: Azure AD Global Admin is not the same as subscription admin. You have to be added as co-admin or given a role in the new portal.

Comment: You may find this link helpful to go with @juunas comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-configure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In new Azure Portal, you should be added as a Co-Owner through the `RBAC` system. You should contact your Account Administrator(AA) who could grant the permission to your subscription.  More information about how to add an admin for a subscription please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing-add-change-azure-subscription-administrator).

More information about RBAC please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-what-is).

Answer (score 1):

You are the admin of the Azure AD directory, but not any subscriptions in that directory (assuming there are subscriptions). Directory admins don't have access to subscriptions by default. A subscription admin will need to grant you access to a subscription.

Note that directories can be created without subscriptions, so not every directory has an Azure subscription.

Also, a credit card is required to create a new subscription and you can't reference an existing company account without the company's Azure account admin doing that for you. Unfortunately, only one account can have access to do that today.